# PHP Code in HTML

Tags: php, html

here $check variable is from php code..which is bolean...
Actually if users put correct username and password this variables becomes true..
if this variable is true then i want replace the "Login" with "My account"..
how can i do that?
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
if ($check) {
  <a href="myaccount.php" class="almanac">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>My Account</span>
  </a>
} else {
  <a href="login.php" class="almanac">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
      <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>Login</span>
  </a>
}
```

But problem is that $check is defined in php code.

Comment: if it's Boolean and you store it as 1 in you db then you can do if ($check == 1)

Comment: How is the server supposed to know what is PHP and what is HTML? Answer: php tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinct the PHP and the HTML parts.
This should do the trick:

```
  <?php if ($check) { ?>
  <a href="myaccount.php" class="almanac">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
  </svg>
  <span>My Account</span>
  </a>
  <?php } else{ ?>
  <a href="login.php" class="almanac">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 25" class="shape-tab">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-tab"></use>
  </svg>
  <span>Login</span>
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Given the content of the question, it might also be worth pointing out that this needs to be in a PHP file not an HTML file.

Comment: Indeed, however if he managed to have a `$check` variable then I assume he is writing inside a PHP file.

Comment: I would not assume that: "*But problem is that $check is defined in php code*" This suggests that code is in an HTML file.

Comment: How does he know such a variable exists then?

Comment: So he/she has two files. It doesn't exist in the HTML file, of course. Hence "But problem is that $check is defined in php code." Still ambiguous though.

Comment: The above code is in .php file not html..$check variable is defined in same file about the html tag..now i used html tag where the form is made..$check variable is checking the username and password from database..Valentin Mercier,i tried the code you mention but it is not working

Comment: Check your `$check` variable

Comment: Thanks Valentin Mercier..it is working now..yes the problem was $check variable.